# How Memory Management is done by CLR

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, clr

From To Many days I am searching for a detail document which will help me to understand garbage collection done by CLR with example of some lines of coding including some functions,class, value type and reference type. Please share with if there is certain document which shows it step by step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at:

- [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)
- [Garbage Collection Part 2: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx)

I can also recommand Jeffrey Richter's book [C# via CLR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045)

Comment: And also part 2: [Garbage Collection--Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A nice article about it : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Memory-Misconceptions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could probably find the best ressources on MSDN, maybe the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx

(this article is old)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into the more general topic of garbage collection take a look at the book [Garbage Collection: Algorithms for Automatic Dynamic Memory Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471941484).

Answer (score 0):

This video seems to be hot and on topic: [E2E: Erik Meijer and Patrick Dussud - Inside Garbage Collection](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/E2E-Erik-Meijer-and-Patrick-Dussud-Inside-Garbage-Collection)